# How to scroll horizontally repeatedly?

Tags: vim

When i press and hold zl, first the window is moved left by one char and than the cursor starts moving to right. I want to be able to hold zl and the behavior to be the window moving to left, like it is when holding ctrl+e.

Comment: zl and zh are just same as c-e and c-y, aren't they? The cursor stays on the same character. Or I  misunderstand something?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean!.. you want to **hold** some key, ok, I post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to **hold** some key to achieve "repeat" `zl` or `zh`, you have to create a mapping for that, with keys like `ctrl`. That is because, the `z` doesn't work in this way.

E.g. (just an example, you can pick the keys you like to combine with ctrl)

```
nnoremap <c-l> zl
nnoremap <c-h> zh
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write `2zl` for 2 characters and `4zl` for 4 characters and thus you can also use `100zl` for 100, so you just have to write any number before `zl`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i specifically mention that i want the behavior to be like holding ctrl+e or ctrl+y. For example i can write a number before this commands too, but it will be uncomfortable like it is the case with horizontal scrolling.